# Dont know how to Filter an array from API Plattform (Symfony) in Vuejs (script setup)

Tags: arrays, json, vue.js, filter, v-for

in my little local vuejs-project (script setup) i'm receiving dummy-data (getTutorials) from my api (symfony, api plattform).
The dummy-data have a value "true" or "false" from Database-Column "published".
[Dummy-Data in Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZbEJ.png)

**What i have:**
2 columns:

- Left Column: Published
- Right Column: Unpublished

[Picture from the 2 Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyde4.png)

**what i want:**

- *v-for loop* for all Data with boolean "true" in the left Column.
- *v-for loop* for all Data with boolean "false" in the right Column.

**what i have:**

- all data ("true" and "false") are in the left Column.
- no data (with "false") in the right Column.

my Code:

```js
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
import TutorialDataService from "../services/TutorialDataService";

const tutorials = ref("");

const getTutorials = TutorialDataService.getAll()
  .then((response) => {
    tutorials.value = response.data["hydra:member"];
    // console.log(response.data["hydra:member"]);
    console.log("---Retrieve OK---");
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
  });
</script>
```

```html
<template>
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
    <div class="bg-slate-50/10 p-3 rounded-md">Published:
        <ul class="list-disc list-inside">
            <li v-for="item in tutorials" :key="item.id">
                {{ item.title }} - <b>{{ item.published }}</b>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-red-300  p-3 rounded-md text-black">Unpublished:
        <ul class="list-disc list-inside">
            <li class="text-black" v-for="item in filtered" :key="item.id">
                {{ item.title }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

**what i need**:
Dont know how to filter this Dummy-Data with computed or a method.
Can anyone help me to filter the received dummy-data, that i can make a v-for loop for the right Column?

Thank You
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to filter your data when you get it from api:

```js
const getTutorials = TutorialDataService.getAll()
  .then((response) => {
    const data = response.data["hydra:member"]; // Saved this into local variable
    tutorials.value = data.value.filter((item) => !item.published); // Filter to get all tutorials with published = 0
    filtered.value = data.value.filter((item) => !!item.published); // Filter to get all tutorials with published = 1
    // console.log(response.data["hydra:member"]);
    console.log("---Retrieve OK---");
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
  });
```

Using `!` and `!!` operators here, more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT

Comment: Solved. Thank you!
changed this line from
tutorials.value = data.value.filter
to
tutorials.value = data.filter
without "value". it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) in a computed property, like:

```
const notPublished = computed(() => {
    const nP = tutorials.filter(t => {
        return t.published === 0; // 0 is not published?
    });
    
    return nP;
});
```

Remember to import computed from vue:

```
import { ref, computed } from "vue";
```

You can use `notPublished` in your `v-for`:

```
<li v-for="item in notPublished" :key="item.id">
    {{ item.title }} - <b>{{ item.published }}</b>
</li>
```